# C# Automapper from flat view model to nested Dto

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, automapper

I'm trying to map a basically flattened view model to a Dto with nested objects. Having a hard time doing it since the view model properties have different names from the Dto. Here's an illustration of what we're working with.

```
// --- Source ---
public class OrderView 
{ 
  public int order_id {get; set;}
  public string customer_name {get; set;}
  public string customer_last_name {get; set;}
}

public class Order 
{ 
  public int Id {get; set;}
}

public class Customer 
{ 
  public string Name {get; set;}
  public string LastName {get; set;}
}

// --- Dest ---
public class OrderDto
{ 
  public Order Order {get; set;}
  public Customer Customer {get; set;}
}
```

Generally I would just reverse map and that would work but I'm trying to figure out how to do this in a cleaner way than the following:

```
var result = new OrderDto
{
  Order = _mapper.Map<Order>(orderView),
  Customer = _mapper.Map<Customer>(orderView)
}
```

I wonder if something like this is possible

```
var result = _mapper.Map<OrderDto>(orderView);
```

Thank you in advance for nay tips on this.

Answer (score -1):

Theoretically, yes. You will have to make a mapping between `int` and `OrderDto`:

```
CreateMap<OrderView, OrderDto>()
    .ForMember(dest => dest.Order, mce => mce.MapFrom(ov => ov.order_id));
CreateMap<int, Order>()
    .ConstructUsing(x => new Order() { Id = x });
```

But a question you could ask yourself is whether this is a valid case for AutoMapper. Can this mapping still be considered 'auto'? To map between an `int` and an `Order`?

As a personal rule, any mapping profile using more than `.Ignore()` is a code smell in my mind and **might** better be solved using a manual mapping. This is because complex mappings often hide business logic, and the last place anyone expects business logic is in an AutoMapper profile. For example, if the property names between source classes and destination classes do not match, that there is hidden business logic to translate between those two. You might be better off just using a manual mapping:

```
var result = new OrderDto
{
    Order = new Order
    {
        Id = orderView.order_id
    },
    Customer = new Customer
    {
        Name = orderView.customer_name,
        LastName = orderView.customer_last_name
    }
}
```

This puts the business logic in the right place (in full view!), is more readable than the complex AutoMapper mapping I gave above, and has the same amount of lines of code.

Comment: If making a DTO from an entity is not mapping, _nothing_ is mapping :)

Comment: "If all you have is a hammer..." I agree AutoMapper mapping between a DTO and an entity is often a good idea. That's why I provided a (working!) example that'll solve the question posed, which makes receiving a downvote all the more odd.

But I do think you should only use AutoMapper where it is best, and if the DTO and entity differ in structure, then I prefer a manual constructor call.

Comment: That's a poor quality solution for a well known problem in AM. So definitely a use case for AM, just needs a proper mapping.